# What is a common range for pSwapchainImages for VkSwapchainKHR?

Tags: vulkan

Have spent the past week learning Vulkan. Currently struggling with getting a swap chain to work. Currently it throws Invalid Image Object.

However, the pSwapchainImagesCount is several hundreds and I thought it was supposed to be only 2 or so.

Taken from api_dump:

```c
pSwapchainImageCount:           uint32_t* = 236
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common value is being equal to the one provided to `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` (`minImageCount`). Sometimes it may be `minImageCount + 1` (theoretically there is no limit though). It is not allowed to be less than `minImageCount`.

That being said, check your `VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR::minImageCount`.